# Prevent custom field from being updated after first publish

Tags: functions, custom-field, post-meta

I need help preventing a custom field from being updated after it's been published for the first time.

I have posts that has a link to an mp3 file and a description of the file. When it's published, I have a function that removes the link to the mp3 file from the content and adds it to a custom field called `audio_url`.

If I make changes to the post, the mp3 link in the custom field gets removed.

Code in my `functions.php`:

```
function save_url_link( $post_id, $post ){
if ( has_post_format('audio', $post_id)) {
if (! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
  preg_match_all ( "/(http|https):\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/", $post->post_content, $matches );
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', $matches[0][0] ); 
}
  remove_action('save_post', 'save_url_link', 10, 2);
  wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_content' => preg_replace('/(http|https):\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/', "", $post->post_content)));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the audio_url regardless of one was found in the content or not.
Make it conditional:

```
if(preg_match_all ( "/(http|https):\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/", $post->post_content, $matches )) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', $matches[0][0] ); 
}
```

In this case, you could also use preg_match, because you're only looking for a single instance.

Also make sure that your regex does work correctly. Right now, it would get you wrong results if two URLs are in the document, since ".*" is greedy and will match as much as possible. Add a ? to change that behaviour to non-greedyness. While we're at it, let's remove the need to escape every Slash by using different delimiters:

```
"!(http|https)://.*?/(.*?)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)!"
```

You don't really need the parentheses around that second `.*?`, but maybe you have more code that needs it? Also, (http|https) could be written as `https?`, the question mark makes the previous character optional.

Comment: Tried your example and did not work.

Comment: That's kind of vague. What exactly did you try? Is audio_url overwritten with an empty string or is the field removed from the DB completely? When you're editing the post after the initial save, do you see audio_url with the correct value under custom fields?

Comment: Found a solution: `if (get_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', true ) == '') {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', $matches[0][0] ); 
      }`